# RabbitMQ Consumer only consumes a portion of the messages sent

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am sending a small number of messages to a RabbitMQ, but the consumer only consumes two of them. Find below the code for my Producer & Consumer:

```
@Component
public class Producer implements CommandLineRunner {

private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
private final Consumer receiver;
private final ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

public Producer(Consumer receiver, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    this.context = context;
}

private List<Message> extractphoneNumberNumbers(String path){
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList();
    try{
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource(path).getInputStream()));
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(fileReader);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        messages = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<Message>>() {}.getType());
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return messages;
}

public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    List<Message> messagesToPublish = extractphoneNumberNumbers("phoneNumbers");
    AtomicInteger messageId = new AtomicInteger();
    for(Message message : messagesToPublish){
        System.out.println("Sent " + message.toString());
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(App.queueName, new Message(messageId.incrementAndGet(), message.getPhoneNumber()));
    }
    receiver.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    context.close();
}

}


@Component
public class Consumer {
private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
private HashMap<String, Integer> phoneCountryCode = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
private int i = 0;

public void receiveJsonMessages(Message message){
    System.out.println("Received " + message.toString());
    phoneCountryCode.put(message.getCountryCode(), phoneCountryCode.getOrDefault(message.getCountryCode(), 0) + 1);

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : phoneCountryCode.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }

    latch.countDown();
}

public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
    return latch;
}
}
```

---

```
Received 5 - +40722579707 - RO
Sent 0 - +447984627687 - GB
RO 1
Received 6 - +40722579717 - RO
Sent 0 - +447984627657 - GB
RO 2
Sent 0 - +447984627667 - GB
Sent 0 - +447984627677 - GB
Sent 0 - +40722579707 - RO
Sent 0 - +40722579717 - RO
Sent 0 - +40722579727 - RO
```

Goal is to group and count phone numbers by country. I'm just playing around with RabbitMQ at the moment, having no experience with it, so the grouping is ... silly now.

The question is though, why are there only two messages received, rather than 7?

EDIT: I believe is due to the fact the beans stop once the workers (the Producer) are finished. How  can I configure this to stop after the Consumers are finished?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
final static String queueName = "rtap-queue";

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, false);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("rtap-exchange");
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queueName);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    return container;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Consumer receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveJsonMessages");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: Why is your private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); is 1, when you expect 7 messages? What is the purpose of the latch here?

Comment: I'm using CountDownLatch for each message to signal the message was received.

Comment: I see that setting the number of consumers to be the same as the number of messages produced, the application outputs the correct counts, however, this seem to mean that each consumer will consume only one message. How could I configure one consumer to consume all messages?

Comment: If you specify a single consumer, and a latch with 7-the number of messages you expect, it should consume all.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the sample here, https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-spring-amqp.html . The important piece is

```
@RabbitHandler
public void receive(String in) {
    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + in + "'");
}
```

The method runs in a loop behind the scene and consumes messages when ever they are available. If you really want to close the context like above, you need to know the number of messages going to be consumed and configure a CountDownLatch with the number of messages expected. When ever you receive the message, you can count down and await on the latch in the main thread. This however, does not guaranty that you will receive all messages, there is no guaranty anything may happen such as network failure. Then you may configure a timeout on your latch wait.

Comment: Unless I match the number of concurrent consumers to the number of messages sent to the queue, the consumer will consume the wrong number of messages

Comment: I've added my app code as well. Would you please take a look?

Comment: container.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
   container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL); lines are redundant if you want the data to be consumed by a single consumer. Next, correct this on your consumer     receiver.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);. With count down latch 1, the context will be closed right after the first message and you will not see the rest of the messages.